# Prove that $\sqrt[2012]{2012!}<\sqrt[2013]{2013!}$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, roots, factorial

I need to prove that $\sqrt[2012]{2012!}<\sqrt[2013]{2013!}$

My attempt:

Let $a=\sqrt[2012]{2012!}$ and $b=\sqrt[2013]{2013!}$

Then $\displaystyle\frac{b^{2012}}{a^{2012}}=\frac{2013}{b}$

Clearly $\displaystyle b<2013$ so $\dfrac{2013}{b}>1\implies \dfrac{b^{2012}}{a^{2012}}>1\implies b>a$

I want to know if this is valid and if there is a better way of proving it.

Comment: You tagged the question as "contest math", can you therefore please include the source of the question?

Comment: Perhaps [Stirling's formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation) might also come in handy.

Comment: @Listing Kosovo National Mathematical Olympiad 2013

Comment: @Lucian Why would that help? $\frac{2013!}{2012!}$ is just $2013$ ($\frac{n!}{(n-1)!} \equiv n$)

Comment: Fun fact related to this question: The function $f(x) = \sqrt[x]{x}$ has a maximum at $(e, \sqrt[e]{e})$ and is decreasing on the right of the maximum to infinity. Also, the derivative of $\sqrt[x]{x!}$ is $e^{-1}$.

Answer (score 4):

For integer $n>0$, $$\{(n+1)!\}^{\frac1{n+1}}> \{n!\}^{\frac1n}\iff \{(n+1)!\}^n> \{n!\}^{n+1}$$ (Taking lcm$(n,n+1)=n(n+1)$th power in either side)

$$\iff(n+1)^n\cdot\{n!\}^n>\{n!\}^{n+1} \iff (n+1)^n>n! $$ which is true as $n+1>r$ for $1\le r\le n$

Answer (score 0):

My proof: ($n=2012$, $n+1=2013$). 
$$\begin{align}((n!)^{\frac{1}{n}})^n &< ((n+1)^{\frac{1}{n+1}})^n \\
n! &< ((n+1)!)^{1-\frac{1}{n+1}} \\
n! &< (n+1) \cdot n! \cdot (n+1)!^{-\frac{1}{n+1}} \end{align}$$
Since $(n+1)!^{\frac{1}{n+1}} < n+1$, we have $(n+1)!<(n+1)^{n+1}$.